# Googliser and list of files

Tags: bash, darwin

I'm downloading images using googliser in a Mac. I have a `googliser.sh` were I can ask for some phrase:

```
$ ./googliser.sh --phrase "Mona Lisa – Leonardo da Vinci" --title 'Mona Lisa_Leonardo_da_Vinci' --upper-size 100000 --lower-size 2000
```

It works, but I want to download +100 images images, so I would like to connect the script with a csv file with the list the images and the names of the files, like this:

```
Mona Lisa – Leonardo da Vinci, 103784
The scream - Munch, 78332
The Starry Night - Vincent van Gogh, 34763
etc.
```

Can anyone tell me if this is possible with the Darwin?

Thanks!

PD: as said in the comments, solved problems running googliser on Mac: https://gist.github.com/dardo82/567eac882b678badfd097bae501b64e2. The script proposed by @sbarzowski runs perfectly on linux:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir output
while read line; do
  phrase="$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1)"
  filename="$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f2)"
  echo "phrase: $phrase"
  echo "filename: $filename"
  # googliser uses phrase with spaces replaced with underscores
  # as image directory
  image_dir="$(echo "$phrase" | sed 's/ /_/g')"
  # in case it already exists
  rm -rf "./$image_dir"

  ./googliser.sh --phrase "$phrase" --upper-size 100000 --lower-size 2000 -g -n1
  mv "./$image_dir"/* "output/$filename"
done <data.csv
```

But on Mac it doesn't work; maybe because there is no `read line` command on Darwin. Some idea of the relative command?

Comment: Please provide the desired result. Do you want to produce a number of separate googliser mosaics (basically running googliser.sh separately for each phrase)? Or maybe you want to have one output file with various pictures? First variant is def. very easy, the other one not necessarily. And what do these numbers in csv mean?

Comment: Hi!, I don't need the mosaic (I forgot the option for this, "-g"). The perfect output would be separate images with the numbers of the csv as names of the files —"103784"—.

Comment: Hello again, I have checked in on a Mac. It seems to me the googliser itself (at least it's current version) doesn't work on a Mac. There is little you can do about it without modifying the googliser script.

Comment: Yesterday, before trying the script, I made it work. Don't ask how, but it was working… I did something with the packages of brew, and then, stopped working. It say something about `ls: illegal option -- I`. Tried to solve it installing gnu commands with `brew install coreutils`, no success… As this is a new question I think I'll open a new thread ;)

Comment: Asked about the problem with ln -I here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544754/searching-images-with-googliser-sh-in-mac-ls-illegal-option-i]

Comment: Found the answer, here: https://gist.github.com/dardo82/567eac882b678badfd097bae501b64e2

Comment: What exactly is happening? Are you able to download pictures manually with modified googliser? I tried running the script with the modified googliser from the gist you posted and I'm unable to download anything. ("!! search phrase (-p --phrase) was unspecified" - even though it was). The rest of the script runs fine on my OS X. Note however that I use a reasonably modern bash from homebrew, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is easy. Just iterate through the file and for each line call googliser.

Full solution (I checked it works):

```
mkdir output
while read line; do
  phrase="$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1)"
  filename="$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f2)"
  echo "phrase: $phrase"
  echo "filename: $filename"

  # googliser uses phrase with spaces replaced with underscores
  # as image directory
  image_dir="$(echo "$phrase" | sed 's/ /_/g')"
  # in case it already exists
  rm -rf "./$image_dir"

  ./googliser.sh --phrase "$phrase" --upper-size 100000 --lower-size 2000 -g -n1
  mv "./$image_dir"/* "output/$filename"
done <data.csv
```

Of course it's quick & dirty, but that should be enough if you just need to run this a few times. If you need it more solid you need to parse the csv properly (with escaping) and handle errors. In such case Python/Perl/Ruby would probably be a better tool.

Comment: I almost got there. it creates the folders, but not the files. I get a "illegal option -- f", and a "illegal option -- p". ¿Maybe is this because I'm on Darwin…

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the script from @sbarzowski works perfectly on my linux. I have problems running it on mac:

```
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
ls: illegal option -- I
```

But it has to do with the configuration of Darwin. So I will open another question.

Thanks!

Comment: Solved problems running googliser in Mac, found the answer here:https://gist.github.com/dardo82/567eac882b678badfd097bae501b64e2. Script for reading files running on linux, but as the question was about Darwin, I update.